# Is it possible to compile Pygame 1.9.2 with SDL 1.3?

Tags: compilation, sdl, pygame

In [this comment](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issue/107/pygame-192-release#comment-1073767), user "illume" seems to indicate that Pygame 1.9.2 will build with "new SDL". Hoping that "new SDL" meant SDL 1.3, I downloaded, compiled and installed [SDL 1.3's source](http://www.libsdl.org/tmp/SDL-1.3.tar.gz), then downloaded Pygame 1.9.2's [source](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame) via `hg` and attempted to install, but I get the error messages detailed [here](https://gist.github.com/1865547). Am I wrong in my interpretation of illume's comment as indicating that Pygame 1.9.2 will build with SDL 1.3, or is there something I can do to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no mention of SDL 1.3/2.0 [there](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issue/107/pygame-192-release#comment-1073767).  "new SDL" might be referring to the [1.2.15 release in January](http://www.libsdl.org/download-1.2.php).

Among other things they removed the CD-ROM API in SDL 2.0.  You can see evidence of that at the bottom of your gist.

You'll have to remove or stub out that functionality in pygame.